# Rails 4.2 Creating Multiple New Records with One Form

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models: Lesson, Questions and Answers.

What I'm trying to do is on the show lesson view, display the questions and allow users to create answers for each answer.  However, I'm not sure the best way to do this.

I tried this approach on my `lesson#show`view:

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
  <%= question.content %><br /><br />
  <%= simple_form_for :answers do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :content %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :question_id, :value => question.id %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

With this code, I receive the error `param is missing or the value is empty: lesson`

Answer has two fields: content, question_id.

My other concern is that I'd like to have this be user friendly, so if there are multiple questions, there should be multiple input boxes for the answers (one per each question) and one submit button (so multiple answers can be posted at one time).

I think that my approach my bad, but I'm not sure how else to do this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I have so far:

Models:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :answers, through: :questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lesson
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Lessons Controller

```
class LessonsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @questions = @lesson.questions
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /lessons/1
  # PATCH/PUT /lessons/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @lesson.update(lesson_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @lesson, notice: 'Lesson was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @lesson }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @lesson.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end     

 private

    def lesson_params
      params.require(:lesson).permit(:name,
      answers_attributes: [:id, :content, :question_id]
      )
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :lessons
  post '/lessons/:id', to: "lessons#update"
```

Comment: You should take a look at Cocoon gem which handles nested forms...

Comment: And your code is breaking because you are not calling the 'set_lesson' method in a before_action. Put `before_action :set_lesson` at the top of your Controller.

Comment: That code is in the controller, the view would not display the show view if it was missing.

Comment: You didn't post it :)

Comment: have you tried this `simple_form_for question.answers.build` instead of `simple_form_for :answers` ?

Comment: Should the user be able to view/edit previous answers on the `lessons#show` page? Or it is a kind of  'write only' form - only questions and single text field for each question, which creates new answer?

Comment: The User will be able to see previous Answers in `lessons#show`

Answer (score 0):

Add gem in Gemfile and run bundle install:-

```
gem "nested_form"
```

On lession show page:-

```
<%= nested_form_for @lession do |lession_form| %>
    <%= @lession.content %>        
    <%= lession_form.fields_for :questions do |question_form| %>
        <% @questions.each do |question| %>
            <%= question.content %><br /><br />
            <%= question_form.fields_for :answers do |answer_form| %>
                <%= answer_form.text_field :content %>
                <%= answer_form.link_to_remove "Remove this answer" %>
            <% end %>
            <%= question_form.link_to_add "Add more answer", :answers %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= lession_form.submit 'Update' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm trying to create a nested form, I know it may look like it from my code, but like I said, I think my approach is wrong.  All I'm trying to do is create an answer field for each question and allow someone to populate all of the answers and submit with on button.  With a nested form, it would allow the lesson taker (i.e. student) to change the questions which would not be good.

Comment: Here, I am displaying question not a text field for question. So, student can add their answers only.

Comment: Thanks, I added the code making a minor correction (changing "lession" to "lesson".  However, the form is now seems to be looping the questions twice.  The questions loop (with answers) as many times as there are questions (i.e. three questions, it loops three times).  Please note, that I also don't need to javascript links to add more records here (although I included it to test this code).

Comment: The other issue I received was "Answer(#54415320) expected, got Array(#7893924)" on submit.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought you are able to achieve without the use of a Gem.

#### You may need to specify inverse_of in your model. I have previously found this was required in nested attributes when dealing with forms.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lesson
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy, :inverse_of => :question
end

class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy, :inverse_of => :lessons
  has_many :answers, through: :questions
  #etc.
end
```

#### In your lessons controller:

```
def show
  @lesson = Question.find(params[:id])
  @questions = @lesson.questions
  x.times { @lesson.questions.answer.build }
end
```

#### In your views/lessons/show page:

```
<%= form_for @lesson do |lesson| %>
  <%= @lesson.whatever_attribute %>
  <%= lesson.fields_for :questions do |question| %>
    <% @questions.each do |question| %>
      <%= question.content %>
    <% end %>
      <div id="answers-div" class='form-group'>
        <%= question_form.fields_for :answers do |answer| %>
          <%= answer.text_field :content id:"answer-entry" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= lesson.submit 'Submit' %>
```

#### Below the form add some buttons to add further answers or remove:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="addNewAnswer">Add Another Answer Box</button><br>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="deleteNewAnswer">Delete Last Answer</button>
```

You can then add & remove answers on the fly with jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#addNewAnswer").click(function() {
    $("#answers-div").append(createNewInputElement($("#answers-div")));
  });
});

function createNewInputElement(form) {
  var newIndex = $("#answers-div").children('input#choice-entry').length;
  var newInput = $("#answer-entry").clone().attr('name', generateNewInputName(newIndex));
  newInput.val('');
  return newInput;
 };

 function generateNewInputName(idx) {
   return "question[answers_attributes][" + idx + "][content]"
 };


 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#deleteNewAnswer").click(function() {
     if ($("#answers-div input").length > 1) {
       $("#answers-div input:last-child").remove();
     }
   });
 });
```

The use of a nested form is not an issue. You require a nested form to allow you to nest answers within your `lessson.questions` but you are only allowing the user to give input

If using Rails 4 (and the Strong params) you will also need to allow these with something along these lines (otherwise the params being passed will not be allowed through).

```
private (in your Lessons controller)

def lesson_params
  params.require(:lesson).permit(:content, answer_attributes:[:content])
end
```

This may not be perfect but it's the start of some sort of solution to your question I would hope.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Yes, a nested form and what you suggest can be done with a gem - such as Cocoon.  I use it for the admin to be able to create the Lesson and Questions.  I understand that you aren't showing the field, but it still seems to leave a vulnerability (similar to the vulnerability Ryan Bates described here http://railscasts.com/episodes/26-hackers-love-mass-assignment-revised?autoplay=true).

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand but I would thought that Strong Params takes care of this for you. As "with this plugin Action Controller parameters are forbidden to be used in Active Model mass assignments until they have been whitelisted." I'm not sure whether the below approach is valid but if it is I would have thought it would address your concern.
  params.require(:lesson).permit(answer_attributes:[:content])

Comment: I'm trying to implement this, but running into a bunch of syntax errors.  I added a missing <% end %> to the form.  It couldn't determine what 'question_form' was in the view, so I tried changing it to 'lesson', but received the same undefined variable.  When I tried to change it to 'question' it gave me an error of undefined method "fields"for".  I think that the controller action was incomplete so I set x to @lesson.questions.count.  The model changes lead to Could not find the inverse association for questions (:lessons in Question).

Comment: Hi - I didn't test it my code editor so apologies for syntax errors. ```question_form``` should simply have been ```question``` as you working with the ```<%= lesson.fields_for :questions do |question| %>``` loop at that point. Also, perhaps ```:inverse_of => :lesson rather than lessons.```

Comment: After reading this(https://viget.com/extend/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations) excellent post on ```inverse_of``` I think it is probably not require because 1) As of version 4.1, Rails will try to automatically set the :inverse_of option for you. 2) It is required when creating an object and its children via accepts_nested_attributes_for in a :has_many association. In your case you have already created the parent object so I makes it unnecessary I would say.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  However, as I tried to say in my comment from Dec 3, when I tried to change it to 'question' it gave me an error of undefined method "fields"for".

Comment: Looks to be an error in the each loops. I should have ended the <% @questions.each do |question| %> earlier. I have now edited the answer. Would expect this to at least move you beyond the "error of undefined method "fields"for"."

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to get me past that issue.  The problem now is the issue I ran into with the answer below.  The questions and answers loop, so that every question appears twice.

Comment: Also, I'm running into params issues when I look in the logs (so it's not posting), `Unpermitted parameter: questions_attributes.`  I'm even getting that when my params are defined as: `params.require(:lesson).permit(:name, :short_descripion, :text, :image, :video,
      questions_sttributes: [:content, answer_attributes: [:id, :content, :question_id]]
      )`

Comment: You can probably remove the <% @questions.each do |question| %> loop and the associated <% end %> and leave the  <%= question.content %> as it within the other fields_for loop. This should prevent the double render.

Comment: If I remove that I get an error when trying to display the question `undefined method `content' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x6b63310>`.

Comment: I am not sure but can perhaps attach the  <%= lesson.fields_for @questions.each do |question| %> somehow??

Answer (score 0):

Try to testing this code, an email me again 
in your lesson#show.html.erb

```
<% for question in @lesson.questions  %>
    <%= question.content %><br /><br />
    <%= simple_form_for :answers do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :content %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :question_id, :value => question.id %>
      <%= f.button :submit %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This might work if I wanted one form per question, but as mentioned above, if there are multiple Questions, I want to put them in one form so it's more user friendly.